# How can I get update-grub to recognize linux-surface kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, surface

I have a Surface Pro 4. The linux surface kernel ([github](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface)) provides better hardware support than the stock kernels, but unfortunately, `update-grub` doesn't recognize it.

I am able to put an entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom/`, but I have to do this manually every time there's a kernel update.

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry 'Ubuntu (4.19.139-surface-lts)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        savedefault
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  cf93f3eb-59be-4eba-835b-03ac8f082424
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cf93f3eb-59be-4eba-835b-03ac8f082424
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.139-surface-lts root=UUID=cf93f3eb-59be-4eba-835b-03ac8f082424 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.139-surface-lts
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

How can I get `update-grub` to recognize the linux-surface kernels automatically?

EDIT: More information

- [dpkg --list | grep linux-image](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qYnN45Dg4z/)
- [grub.cfg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2FPg9yQJ9x/) -- notice that it adds an extraneous "timeout: menu" after 30_OS_Prober
- [update grub, 40_custom, and ls /boot](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sRhSH8trFk/)

Comment: I learned that the extraneous "timeout: menu" is a Ubuntu decision to use Menu for all dual-boot setups, regardless of what is in /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 0):

Add as 06_custom file in /etc/grub.d/06_custom
In /etc/default/grub
Change GRUB_DEFAULT=6
Default set to 0 to boot 00_header
6 to match 06_custom
i think that's how the numbers work for menu entries
I may have missed a few steps :)

This Grub Manual Has just about everything u need very useful :)

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Overview

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- I see 40_custom (which I am using already) and custom.cfg, but no 06_custom. My question is: "Shouldn't my kernel be found by 10_linux? Why did that fail? How can I make 10_linux not fail."

Comment: Create a file Called 06_custom add to  /etc/grub i dont why it has to be 06-09 before 10 but thats what tutorial (lol i lost my tutorial for this somewhere if i find will post) recommended and afterwards as ibster said-- Sorry for confusion i did say add as 06_custom not add new file named 06_custom, as for making 10 work correctly i dont know thats new to me :) (maybe set Grub_default=10 so it can read 10_linux)